# Bootstrap 4: Right-align content inside grid cell

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The following html on a small screen results in overlapping columns:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary">New</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <form method="get">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-8">
          <input name="custName" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Seach</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <nav aria-label="Pagination">
      <ul class="pagination float-right">
        <li><a class="page-link" href="#">Prev</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I need to right-align nav element. How can I prevent overlapping of columns?

Comment: Add a fiddle (code that can be run) so that we can see the bug in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. It's working as design. There are only certain amounts of spaces you can have, and obviously you can't put everything there and expect they will still look nice and be in one row.

You can change the breakpoint from `sm` to maybe `lg` so that those columns will become rows earlier?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/111085/